# Javascript nesting objects returns undefined

Tags: javascript, object

I have this function:

```
var MyApp = {}; // Globally scoped object

function foo(){
    MyApp.color = 'green';
}

function test(){
    alert(MyApp.color); // Alerts 'green'
}
```

But instead of `green` in alert it says `undefined`. Why? And how ito fix it.

Comment: You never called the `foo` function, so why would the property be set ?

Comment: *"And how ito fix it."* `foo(); test();`

Answer (score 2):

`foo` is never run, so `MyApp.color` never receives any value and is therefor undefined.